# Not able to write to Videobuffer in own OS

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, bootloader, osdev

I started writing a small OS and at the moment I don't have any build problems and it looks like everything is working, just something isn't working. I go into video mode in the bootloader and then write to this "array" in the kernel or to the buffer but nothing happens, the screen stays black and doesn't change a bit. I would be grateful if you would take some time and look at it

I added many comments to the bootloader so I can better understand what's happening
Bootloader:

```s
;; Phase 1: The Initial Jump
;; Bootloader
[ORG 0x7C00]
BITS 16

;; Phase 2: Real Mode Setup
;; Set up the stack
mov ax, 0x9000 ;; move the stack to 0x9000
mov ss, ax     ;; set the stack segment
mov sp, 0xFFFF ;; set the stack pointer

;; A20 Line
mov ax, 0x2401  ;; set up the A20 line
int 0x15        ;; call the BIOS

jmp _main

;; section data 
HelloWorld db "Hello World", 0
disk_error_msg db "Error loading the kernel", 0
debug_msg db "Debugging", 0

;; harddisk
diskPacket
  db 0x10
  db 0x00
num_sectors
  db 0x0040

gdt_start:
  dw 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000 ;; null descriptor
  dw 0xFFFF, 0x0000, 0x9A00, 0x00CF ;; code descriptor
  dw 0xFFFF, 0x0000, 0x9200, 0x00CF ;; data descriptor
gdt_end:


gdt_descriptor:
  dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
  dd gdt_start


_main:
  mov si, HelloWorld
  call print_string
  

  ;; Phase 3: Load the Kernel using FAT12
  ;; running on a harddisk/usb stick
  mov ax, 0x0000 ;; set up the segment
  mov es, ax ;; set the segment
  mov bx, 0x8000 ;; set the offset
  mov ah, 0x02 ;; read disk
  mov al, num_sectors
  mov ch, 0x00 ;; cylinder
  mov cl, 0x02 ;; sector
  mov dh, 0x00 ;; head
  mov dl, 0x80 ;; drive
  int 0x13 ;; call the BIOS
  jc disk_error ;; if there is an error, jump to disk_error
  
  ;; Phase 3.5: Enter video mode
  mov ax, 0x13 ;; the vidoe buffer is at 0xA0000
  int 0x10

  ;; Phase 4: Enter Protected Mode
  cli                   ; Disable interrupts
  lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; Load the Global Descriptor Table
  mov eax, cr0          ; Move the contents of CR0 into EAX
  or al, 1              ; Set the Protection Enable bit
  mov cr0, eax          ; Move the modified CR0 back into the register

  jmp 0x08:protected_mode ; Far jump to the code segment, flushes the pipeline


disk_error:
  mov si, disk_error_msg
  call print_string
  jmp $

print_string:
  mov ah, 0x0E
  mov bh, 0x00
  mov bl, 0x07
.loop:
  lodsb
  cmp al, 0
  je .done
  int 0x10
  jmp .loop
.done:
  ret

[BITS 32]
protected_mode:

  ;; Set up the data segment register
  mov ax, 0x10   ; The selector for the data segment in our GDT is 0x10
  mov ds, ax
  mov es, ax
  mov fs, ax
  mov gs, ax
  mov ss, ax

  ;; set stack
  mov esp, 0x90000

  jmp 0x8000
  ;; Draw a block of color on the screen
  mov edi, 0xA0000          ; Starting address of video memory in mode 0x13
  mov ecx, 320*50           ; we want a 320x50 block, so 16000 pixels
  mov al, 0x0F              ; Random color (White, in this case)
  
.draw_loop:
  stosb                     ; Store AL at address ES:(E)DI, then increment DI
  loop .draw_loop           ; Loop until ECX is zero
  
  jmp $                     ; Infinite loop


;; fill 512 bytes with 0x00
times 510-($-$$) db 0x00
;; magic number
dw 0xAA55
```

linker.ld:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x8000;

    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

entry.c:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

void _start(void)
{
  uint8_t *videomem = (uint8_t *)0xA0000;

  for (int i = 0; i < 320 * 200; i++)
  {
    videomem[i] = 0x0F;
  }

  while (1)
  {
    
  }
}
```

everything compiles fine and links into a disk image.
Makefile in root:

```
# OS booting on QEMU starting in realmode
# Compiler
NASM=nasm
CC=clang
LD=ld.lld
DD=dd

# Files
IMG=img/os.img
BOOTLOADER=bootloader/dist/bootloader.bin
KERNEL=kernel/dist/kernel.o

# Targets
.PHONY: all run clean

all: $(IMG)

# Build the bootloader
$(BOOTLOADER):
    make -C bootloader all

# Build the kernel
$(KERNEL):
    make -C kernel all

# Create the disk image
$(IMG): $(BOOTLOADER) $(KERNEL)
    $(DD) if=/dev/zero of=$(IMG) bs=1M count=100
    $(DD) if=$(BOOTLOADER) of=$(IMG) conv=notrunc
    $(DD) if=$(KERNEL) of=$(IMG) seek=1 conv=notrunc

run: $(IMG)
    qemu-system-i386 -drive format=raw,file=$(IMG)

gdb: $(IMG)
    qemu-system-i386 -drive format=raw,file=$(IMG) -s -S

clean:
    make -C bootloader clean
    make -C kernel clean
    rm -f $(IMG)
```

Comment: Make sure you compile the C code as 32 bit (`-m32`).

Comment: First isolate the problem to either the bootloader or the "kernel".

Comment: I do use -m32 but thanks @Jester

Comment: Works here. Verify compiler generated code.

Comment: When you single-step this or set a breakpoint in GDB attached to QEMU (as a GDB-remote), are the expected bytes at linear address `0xA0000`?  What about when you single-step from your bootloader into the compiler-generated asm of the kernel?  Bochs also has a good built-in debugger which knows about segmentation, unlike GDB, in case your code has problems before getting into protected mode.

Comment: @Jester I just checked and im not sure but I think the compiler (my makefile) is broken....

gdb gave me this:
```
0x0000fff0 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/10i 0x8000
   0x8000:      add    %al,(%eax)
   0x8002:      add    %al,(%eax)
   0x8004:      add    %al,(%eax)
   0x8006:      add    %al,(%eax)
   0x8008:      add    %al,(%eax)
   0x800a:      add    %al,(%eax)
   0x800c:      add    %al,(%eax)
   0x800e:      add    %al,(%eax)
   0x8010:      add    %al,(%eax)
   0x8012:      add    %al,(%eax)
```

Comment: @Jester I think the dd command fails because I dont see any code except "add" instructions at 0x8000
`  $(DD) if=$(KERNEL) of=$(IMG) seek=64 conv=notrunc`
(this is the only line i changed in the makefile)

Comment: If you only changed that it won't work, since your code is reading sector 2.